# What could affect jpeg quality when cropping on different machines?

Tags: c#, image-resizing, imageresizer

I'm using a 3rd party library (ImageResizing.net) to crop an image but on a specific system (2008 server) it is coming out with a red tint.

The C# below uses ImageResizer.net 3.4.2 via nuget.

```
    private static void ApplyCrop(string sourceDir)
    {
        var sourceImagePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourceDir, "before.jpg");
        var outputImagePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourceDir, "after.jpg");

        var cropSettings = new ResizeSettings();
        cropSettings.CropTopLeft = new System.Drawing.PointF(0,0);
        cropSettings.CropBottomRight = new System.Drawing.PointF(1003,990);
        cropSettings.Width = 1000;
        cropSettings.Height = 1200;
        cropSettings.Quality = 100;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(outputImagePath))
            System.IO.File.Delete(outputImagePath);
        ImageBuilder.Current.Build(sourceImagePath, outputImagePath, cropSettings);
    }
```

I have set jpeg quality to 100 which should be zero-compression. You can see the difference in the [image: tinted image]

I really don't think it is a problem with the 3rd party library but the image codecs used on the server. **How would I go about figuring out what DLL is being used and are there any recommended, safe to use (no spam, adware etc) codecs?**

Answer (score 1):

It may not even be a codec - it may just be the monitor display profile used by the machine. Try setting it back to sRGB and see if it goes away.

GDI+ doesn't give you much control over ICC profiles - your only available setting is to ignore the image's included ICC profile (ignoreicc=true in ImageResizer) - but this may not help if your display profile is causing the issue.

Also, none of the other (non-default) pipelines should be affected (freeimage, wic).

#### Update - after receiving the original file

The image is a Photoshop-only CMYK jpeg using the Adobe "U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2" color profile. GDI+ can't color-adjust this, but our FreeImage pipeline should be able to, if you download the latest native dlls from http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html The ones currently bundled with ImageResizer use speed optimizations that preclude accurate CMYK ICC profile translation.

Comment: So if I converted it to use WIC or freeimage then it would bypass the possible GDI+ issue?

Comment: Yes, but they use different resizing algorithms. WIC's is a bit poorer (but much faster). FreeImage is the same or better quality, but much slower. Fixing the profile issue might be better.